# Why does my function keep returning a longer list?

Tags: python

I opened my python interpreter, coded up and ran the following function.

```
>>> def crazy_function(my_list=[]):
...     my_list.append(0)
...     return my_list
... 
>>> crazy_function()
[0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0, 0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> crazy_function()
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

What is going on? Why does the list returned by the function keep getting longer the more I call the function? Shouldn't a new local list be created every time the function is called?

Comment: This gets asked a lot - see ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: These questions always get closed *SO FAST*.  It's impressive.

Comment: omg, wow. Thanks for directing me to a resource. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common error to assign mutable objects to a function argument's default value. Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed.** This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used
>   for each call. This is especially important to understand when a
>   default parameter is a mutable object, such as a list or a dictionary:
>   if the function modifies the object (e.g. by appending an item to a
>   list), the default value is in effect modified. This is generally not
>   what was intended.